# Bash cannot process git output one-by-one, items stuck together

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to run a script like below:

```
Changed_Files=$(git diff --diff-filter=dr --name-only origin/main..."$My_branch" | grep '^\s*foo/') 
  
for file in "${Changed_Files[@]}"; do 
  subdir=$(echo "$file" | cut -d / -f 2)
  if [[ "$subdir" == "bar1" ]]; then
    func1 "$file"
  else 
    echo ("Error")
    exit(1)
  fi
done
```

Sample `Changed_Files`:

```
foo/bar1/file1.json
foo/bar1/file2.json
```

**Expected Result:**

`func1` gets run on both files.

**Actual Result:**

The script exits because `subdir` evaluates to `bar1 bar1`. Instead of processing the files one-by-one, the variable `file` will always contain the entire list of results from `git diff`.
I also tried

```
for i in "${!Changed_Files[@]}"; do
  file="${Changed_Files[$i]}"
  ...
```

But this gives the same result. How can I process items returned from `git diff` one-by-one instead of the entire output stuck together?

Comment: When assigning to an array, the value needs to be wrapped into parenthesis: `Changed_Files=($(...))`

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation. Also `Changed_Files` is not an array.

Comment: You need to actually define an array. Your "array" is a string.

Comment: And don't do it the way @svlasov said -- that approach is subject to all the bugs discussed in [BashPitfalls #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_.2BICY.29_.29)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How would you recommend reading the `git diff` output into an array?

Comment: Error messages belong on stderr.  Always.  `echo "Error" >&2`

Comment: @lem, see the link edited into my comment above.

Comment: (to extend what William said above -- not just error messages but status, logging, and informational messages meant for a human operator also belong on stderr; stdout is _only_ for output meant to be passed to later pipeline components/written to output files/etc)

Comment: @lem, btw, if you have time to take another look, I added a pure-bash implementation that'll work in bash 3.x, vs the original answer only targeting 4.0 and newer. Do let me know if there's anywhere in it more explanatory notes are called for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that would cause the symptom described is that you're storing output in a string, not an array.

The right way to fix that in bash 4.x and later is:

```
readarray -t Changed_Files < <(git diff --diff-filter=dr --name-only origin/main..."$My_branch" | grep '^\s*foo/')
```

But don't use that exactly as given: `\s` is a PCRE extension, and POSIX-compliant grep implementations aren't guaranteed to support it. Use `[[:space:]]` instead.

---

If you need to support bash 3.x (like the version included with MacOS as well), you might consider a rewrite entirely in native shell, not relying on any external tools other than `git diff` itself:

```
# feature needed for +( ) to work; in older bash releases, even needed in PEs
shopt -s extglob

parentDirTgt=foo # the thing you were grepping for in original code

errors_seen=0
while IFS=/ read -r parentDir subDir rest <&3; do # fd 3 has "git diff" output
  parentDir=${parentDir##+([[:space:]])}          # strip leading whitespace
  [[ $parentDir = $parentDirTgt ]] || continue    # skip files not under parent
  [[ $rest ]] || continue       # skip files not under two directory layers
  file=$parentDir/$subDir/$rest # reconstruct full file name
  case $subDir in               # branch on subdirectory layer
    bar1) func1 "$file";;       # for directory foo/bar1, call function func1
    *)    echo "Ignoring change in unrecognized subdirectory $subDir" >&2
          errors_seen=1;;
  esac
done 3< <(git diff --diff-filter=dr --name-only origin/main..."$My_branch")

exit "$errors_seen"
```

This probably calls for some explanation.

- The `while read` looping practice is covered in [BashFAQ #1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Instead of reading each line into *just one* variable, we split on `/`s and read into three variables: `parentDir`, `subDir`, and `rest` (containing everything after the second `/`).
- The use of `<( )` instead of `|` to connect `git diff` to the loop is for reasons described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- The use of `+([[:space:]])` is an [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) that matches as many spaces as possible, used in the context of the `${var##pattern}` [parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to strip the longest possible matching pattern from the beginning of a variable's contents.
- File descriptor 3 is used so that anything in `func1` that tries to read from stdin will actually consumer original stdin instead of the `git diff` output.

See this running an an online sandbox at https://ideone.com/ZA1Cgn